# How to make this video autoplay?

Tags: html, video, flash, autoplay

I have some `html` code for a page that has a video included on it. I'm trying to figure out how to make the `video` automatically play once the page is loaded. Is this possible and if so how?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="letplayer" width="640" height="360" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
    <param name="movie" value="//moevideo.net/swf/letplayer.swf?_=20082014" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param value="file=23891.2187961fd18487cc66b952ed8992" name="flashvars">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <embed src="//moevideo.net/swf/letplayer.swf?_=20082014"
           quality="high"
           bgcolor="#000000"
           width="640" height="360" name="letplayer"
           align="middle"
           play="true"
           loop="false"
           quality="high"
           allowFullScreen="true"
           allowScriptAccess="always"
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
           flashvars="file=23891.2187961fd18487cc66b952ed8992"
           name="letplayer"
           wmode="opaque"
           pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </embed>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If've just googled it and found a code with this line:

```
<embed src="...." play="true" />
```

Comment: play="true" is already called in <embed> </embed>? or should I add it somewhere else?

Comment: sorry didn't saw it! what browser do you use? do you have tried it with an other video, etc. from youtube or so?

Comment: Firefox I've tried with Chrome though. I need it to work with this video from the source in the code so no point in trying with youtube.

Comment: next try ;D
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
or play="true" -> autoPlay="true"

Answer (score 0):

In html 'video' tag has the attribute 'controls' , we can set it as 'autoplay'

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
```

please refer the link http://edvista.com/claire/qt/embedtags/

```
<EMBED SRC="juliana.mov" WIDTH="160" HEIGHT= "136" AUTOPLAY="TRUE">
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this will work in my code? Care to show me where I should edit?

Comment: i am not a master in HTML, the above link may help you